# Get a command from history without execution in bash

Tags: bash, history

To use a command from history you can write like `$!100`.
But sometimes I make a little change of the command.

Is there a way to get a command from history without executing it.

Now I'm copying and paste from history by using mouse. I want to know how to do it by using only keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
shopt -s histverify
```

Using that, you'll get the expansion of the history command, and can edit it before executing. From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html):

> If the `histverify` shell option is enabled, and Readline is being used, history substitutions are not immediately passed to the shell parser. Instead, the expanded line is reloaded into the Readline editing buffer for further modification.

You can put this option into Bash's configuration files (e.g. `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` depending on [which you use](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)) to have it enabled automatically.

Comment: So there is a shopt for it. I didn't know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Bash, start typing the first few letters of the command and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to start a history search. You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to continue searching backwards in your Bash history. When you find the command you'd like, use the arrow keys to select/navigate around the command to edit and execute to your needs.

You can also hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> with an empty command buffer and start your search from there.

Comment: Thanks for your Information. But I prefer to use history command.

Comment: You asked for (and received) an answer using only the keyboard. I'm not sure it gets any easier than using Ctrl+R.

Comment: Sorry, I should stated more accurately what I want. I'll try to get used to the way that you showed me.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the history search via ctrl+r already mentioned, you can use the history entry number method you are already familiar with:

```
!<history entry number>
```

in the middle of other commands like

```
echo !100
```

and even reference arguments from previous commands.  For instance suppose in my history, entry 100 was:

```
ping google.com
```

I could do a host lookup on google by pulling the first argument from that history entry like so:

```
host !100:1
```

This works for the special reference to the previous command

```
!!
```

as well.  Of course for the numbered entries, you have to know their entry number by either typing history and looking, or piping to grep.  If you want to pull from your history by matching the text, you can use the text from a previous command in the ! statement.  For example using the fact that I have that ping google.com statement in my history, I can reference it like:

```
host !ping:1
```

The thing to keep in mind with the search by text method is that it searches backwards and pulls the first match.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace any string in the previous command with the `^^` operator. Not sure what it is called. Otherwise (not last command), use Garrett's suggestion.

```
$ ping 10.3.0.3
PING 10.3.0.3 (10.3.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.3.0.3: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.333 ms
64 bytes from 10.3.0.3: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.251 ms
^C
--- 10.3.0.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.251/0.292/0.333/0.041 ms
```

magic here:

```
$ ^ping^finger
finger 10.3.0.3
The program 'finger' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install finger
```

Comment: slhck mentions how to enable further modification of commands recalled with `^^`.

Comment: I never seen ^^ operator. Thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get a command from history without executing it?

Maybe I’m missing the point of the question, as I doubt that I’m the only person who knows about `:p`.  It stands for “print”.  If you type `!100:p`, the shell will print (i.e., display) command #100 without executing it.

If you don’t know about the `:` operators in history, you should learn. 
[As “numeric illustration” points out](//superuser.com/q/623266/150988#623281),
`:n` retrieves the *n* th word of a command. 
You can also use `:n-m` to get a range;
and there are interesting defaults. 
For example, `:-` (leaving *n* and *m* blank) gets you all the words except for the last one.  `:$` gets you the last word.  `:h` is “head”, so if you type

```
ls -ld /asdfg/qwerty/foo/bar
```

then

```
!:- !$:h
```

turns into

```
ls –ld /asdfg/qwerty/foo
```

Oh, yeah, `!$` is short for `!:$`.  `:s` is substitute, as in `:s/old/new/`. 
This is the same as `^old^new^` except for things like

1. `:s` can be used on any command (as in `!100:s/...`);  `^^` works only on the most recent command.
2. `:s` can be used on individual words, or ranges of words.  For example,

   `!:- !$:s/d/D/`

   gets

   `ls -ld /asDfg/qwerty/foo/bar`

   (rather than `ls -lD ...`).
3. `:s` can be applied globally.  The syntax is non-intuitive, but, where `:s/old/new/` replaces the first occurrence, `:gs/old/new/` replaces every occurrence.

Also, once you've fetched a command from history without executing it
(e.g., with `!100:p`), possibly with modifications (as shown above),
it becomes the most recent command in your history list. 
Now you can press <kbd>↑ (cursor up)</kbd> and edit it.

Comment: Thanks Scott. This is very useful information! May I ask you where can I found more Information? Is there a name of these options?

Comment: @Tetsu: Try the `bash` man page, under the **Modifiers** heading.

Comment: This answer deserves way more upvotes (it now has grand total of 1, including mine)...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to get command history in clipboard (no need to print history and copy it with mouse):

`echo !740 | xclip -sel clip`

Here's some more info about xclip: https://askubuntu.com/questions/184397/how-do-i-pipe-terminal-standard-output-stdout-to-the-clipboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
cat ~/.bash_history
```

...to view the entries in your bash history. If you're looking for something specific, pipe it to grep and search. For example, if I ran a *chmod* command that I want to refer back to, I could run:

```
cat ~/.bash_history | grep chmod
```

...to find those entries. Hopefully I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Sorry, your information is not what I want to know. And you may use `history` command instead of `cat ~/.bash_history`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Sorry it wasn't what you were looking for.